# Grouping lines in cases and aligning them

Tags: equations, align, brackets, subequations, grouping

I am reading an article, where I faced the following:
[image]

I want to write such a thing in LaTeX. Basically, this whole thing is in a bracket, every two lines are grouped and labeled together, and there is also an alignment of three columns within the bracket.

Could you please help?

Comment: Could you please kindly provide us with what you have tried such that we do not have to type the formulae from the screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible e.g. with `empheq`, `align` and `aligned`.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left={\empheqlbrace}]{align}
\begin{aligned}
 d^\mathsf{T}u+\left(1+d^\mathsf{T}r\right)f(\dots) &\le 0 \\ 
 1+d^\mathsf{T}r &\ge 0 
\end{aligned} &\\
\begin{aligned}
 -D_i^\mathsf{T}u+\left(-D_i^\mathsf{T}\right)f(\dots) &\le 0 \\ 
 -D_i^\mathsf{T} &\ge 0 
\end{aligned} & \qquad  i=1,\dots, L
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]